# Shortcut for selecting parent Group in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Questions says it all in a way. I have selected a layer, and I want to press some button combination to select the direct parent of the current selection.

Is there any?

I'm using PS CS4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a script you can select the parent of the currently active layer.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var layerParent = doc.activeLayer.parent;
if ( layerParent !== doc ) doc.activeLayer = layerParent;
```

<sub><sup>Tested up to CS6</sup></sub>

You can save it as `Select Parent.jsx`

If you put the script the the Photoshop scripts folder (eg. `\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Presets\Scripts` on Windows) and restart photoshop, you can set a hotkey to launch the script from `Edit > Keyboard shortcuts...`. You will find the new command under `File > Scripts > Select Parent`

---

Gif of me pressing the hotkey a few times to travel the parent groups up until there aren't any parents left.

[image]

The gif loops after it gets to `Group 4`, which is the last parent group.

Comment: Excellent! To confirm, it works In Photoshop in 2021 (22.3.0 release)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe came out with a solution for this in CS6 I believe, where at the top left of the toolbar you can choose to select a layer or a group upon clicking. I don't think there are any solutions for CS4.

Sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you're after but there is a shortcut key for selecting the layer above which you can keep doing until you get to the parent or group you're after. Try <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>. <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> selects the layer below. <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> or + <kbd>></kbd> selects the bottommost and topmost layer respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If your current layer is in a group and you are trying to select the entire group (the parent in the layers panel that has the little folder icon), then all you need to do is hold down COMMAND (CTRL) and then, with the Move Tool selected, click anywhere inside your document.