# How to switch between group and layers using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

How do I switch, using a keyboard shortcut, from selecting a grouped layer to selecting the layers grouped individually?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the layer navigation shortcuts.

<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> = highlight next layer/group below

<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> = highlight next layer/group above

If the highlight lands on a group, then it's the group.

There's no shortcut I'm aware of to "jump" between or to the next/previous group. And there's no shortcut to toggle the `Auto-select` option of the Move Tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for that...

I usually have `Move tool` set to select `groups` and `auto-select` enabled. I do disable `auto-select` sometimes because with the move tool active, you can temporarily toggle `auto-select` by holding down `Cmd`, which is sometimes better when using the move tool directly.

**I use `Cmd+Alt+Right Click` to select layers in the document.** This works with any tool that can toggle to `Move tool` when pressing `Cmd` (+Move tool itself). In Windows, you use `Ctrl` instead of `Cmd`. Otherwise, it's the same. This method is not tied to the `Move tool` settings and will always select layers no matter what.

...**and if I want to select folders, I `Cmd+Left Click`.** This works assuming `Auto-select` is enabled in the `Move tool` settings. Or if I happen to be using the `Move tool`, I simply `Left Click`.

The `Cmd+Alt+Right Click` method has one quirk that can be annoying or awesome depending on the situation. It selects locked layers, whereas the `Move tool` `Auto-select` doesn't.

---

I also want to mention that I often use the `Cmd+Alt+Right Click` method and [the script mentioned here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/61072/2332) to get its immediate parent.

Very often it's more useful than the `Move tool` group selection method. Let's say you have this layer structure:

- Group 1

  - Layer
  - Group 2

    - Layer
    - Layer
  - Group 3

    - Layer

The `Move tool` group selection will always give you `Group 1`, which basically makes it useless if you'd rather select `Group 2` or `Group 3`.

---

**A second workaround** could be creating two tool presets. One for selecting layers and one for selecting groups. You could then make two Actions for triggering each tool preset. You should give both Actions shortcut keys.

You should disable `Current tool only` in the Tool Presets dropdown that in the left side of the toolbar. This way the actions can be triggered with other tools active. This would be kind of annoying because then you have all tool presets visible in this list at all times. Not so annoying if you don't use it regularly. If you don't do that, you can only use these Actions when `Move tool` is active.

You wouldn't need to disable `Current tool only` if you could record the activation of `Move tool` into an Action, but you can't... You could get around that by using a script, because actions can trigger scripts. Then again you could script the whole process: Select Move tool, Select Preset X. Upside with scripts would be that you have more freedom with the type of Shortcut you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tablet pressure:

We can use  <kbd>control</kbd>  +  <kbd>option</kbd>  + **click** on a Mac, while the Group is active using the Move tool to select a Layer, inside or outside the group either.

Using a mouse:

<kbd>option</kbd>  + **right click**.

I'm not sure about Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible by using scripts and Presets**

***Step 1*** : Create new presets from `Tool Presets` window and if it is hidden then go to `Windows-Tool Presets` to make it Visible, after that create two presets named `AutoGroup` and `AutoLayer`, watch below tutorial to understand more.

[image]

***Step 2*** :Once you create this presets save below scripts and put it in your Photoshop's script folder and reboot your photoshop, to ensure scripts is saved successfully go to `File-Scripts-AutoselectLayer/Group` if you have this scripts then you are ready for final step

**Script 1 = Save below script as AutoselectLayer**

```
cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };  

var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
    var desc13 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref6 = new ActionReference();
        var idmoveTool = stringIDToTypeID( "moveTool" );
        ref6.putClass( idmoveTool );
    desc13.putReference( idnull, ref6 );
    var iddontRecord = stringIDToTypeID( "dontRecord" );
    desc13.putBoolean( iddontRecord, true );
    var idforceNotify = stringIDToTypeID( "forceNotify" );
    desc13.putBoolean( idforceNotify, true );
executeAction( idslct, desc13, DialogModes.NO );



  function Preset(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putName(sTID("toolPreset"), "AutoLayer");
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    executeAction(cTID('slct'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };
Preset();
```

**Script 2 = Save below script as AutoselectGroup.jsx**

```
cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };  

var idslct = charIDToTypeID( "slct" );
    var desc13 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref6 = new ActionReference();
        var idmoveTool = stringIDToTypeID( "moveTool" );
        ref6.putClass( idmoveTool );
    desc13.putReference( idnull, ref6 );
    var iddontRecord = stringIDToTypeID( "dontRecord" );
    desc13.putBoolean( iddontRecord, true );
    var idforceNotify = stringIDToTypeID( "forceNotify" );
    desc13.putBoolean( idforceNotify, true );
executeAction( idslct, desc13, DialogModes.NO );



  function Preset(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
      return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putName(sTID("toolPreset"), "AutoGroup");
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    executeAction(cTID('slct'), desc1, dialogMode);
  };
Preset();
```

***Step 3*** : Now all we need is define shortcut so go to `Edit-Keyboard Shortcut` or <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+Shift+K</kbd> and change shortcut for both script (in my case i used `Ctrl+Alt+Q` and `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Q` ) and now you're done, each time you press your keys it'll auto select your commands XD i know i'm too late but even @Joonas had same idea as i uses and it's so cool :) below is image of working concept.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you just get the setting the active move tool and then select a preset with the other setting? This way you only need one script.

Comment: Yeah. It can be useful but later I'm currently using my plugin so I moved over shortcut keys haha. Guess no need to press hotkeys anymore.

Comment: what's your plugin?

Comment: well it's private called Phoenix Exporter (which used for game design purposes)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/v9Su8vw here is demo image.